# How to find out the page span of a section

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, include

I have several short documents out of which I want to build a larger document, each smaller document corresponding to a section in the larger document.

I want to set the footer to contain the name of the section and the *page span* of the section. So if the first section was named "Hello world" and if it went from pages 4 to 11, I'd like to have the footer to say something like

*Hello World, pp 4 - 11*

I know to set the footer and I'm pretty sure I can get the section name with `\thesection`. I just don't know how to get a reference to the 4-11.

**edit 1** my document class is book and I have `hyperref` loaded

Comment: which documentclass are you using? Do you load hyperref?

Comment: @Dynamite book and yes, respectively

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit fragile, but seems to give the desired result:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
\fancyfoot[c]{%
    \nameref{foo:\thechapter.\@arabic\c@section}%
    \space pp. \pageref{foo:\thechapter.\@arabic\c@section}\space--\space\pageref{bar:\thechapter.\@arabic\c@section}%
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mystartlabel}{%
\label{foo:\thechapter.\@arabic\c@section}
}
\newcommand{\myendlabel}{%
\label{bar:\thechapter.\@arabic\c@section}
}
\makeatother



\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{title}
\mystartlabel
\lipsum

\myendlabel
\section{title2}
\mystartlabel
\lipsum

\myendlabel
\chapter{title}
\section{title3}
\mystartlabel
\lipsum

\myendlabel
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Teepeemm mmm, chapter changes will be a problem, I'll have to think about that. The end page will be correct if the section changes somewhere on the page, only the special case where the old one ends on the previous one will be wrong.

Comment: @Teepeemm I think I fixed the problems by using a second label